# ListView Changing Source Value Keeps the Selected Item Active Unless I revert my changes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

So I have a ListView bound to a Client Object. The client properties are shown on some textbox next to the ListView. If I change the name (that is shown in the ListView), I can't select anything else unless I revert back the name.

The ListView SelectedItem always stays selected if I change the value in the Text Box and the Text Box all show the same values, even if I select another.

I tried clearing the selected item, the ItemsSource nothing will work. It must be something with the source and the bindings.

My Source is a ObservableDictionary that I found somewhere here, so maybe that is the issue. My Client Object is Also implementing INotifyPropertyChanged. I tried a lot of thing with Binding and etc. But whatever I try the text Box will stay like that even if I select something else as long has the value isn't the restored to it's Original Value I can't select anything else.

XAML

```
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ListView x:Name="listView" Grid.RowSpan="7" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5,0" SelectionMode="Single" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ClientIDandName}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

    <TextBlock Text="ID" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedItem.ClientID, ElementName=listView}" IsEnabled="False"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Nom" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedItem.ClientName, ElementName=listView}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Temps de Transit" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedItem.TransitTime, ElementName=listView}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Nbr. de Jour Max" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedItem.MaxShipDays, ElementName=listView}" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Exclure" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding SelectedItem.IsExcluded, ElementName=listView}" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>

    <Button x:Name="btnSave" Content="Sauvegarder" Click="btnSave_Click" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

Code Behind

```
    public partial class ClientConfig : UserControl
{
    public ClientConfig()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listView.ItemsSource = Client.LocalDB.Values.ToObservableCollection();
    }

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Client client = listView.SelectedItem as Client;

        if (client != null)
        {
            client.Save();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the MVVM design pattern and keep my objects in a viewmodel, so you will have to modify the code accordingly.

I think that your problem is how you create your ObservableCollection in code.  When you call ToObservableCollection(), it enumerates all of the values in Client.LocalDB.Values, but I don't think it will persist as an object like you expect it to - especially since it is local to the method that you are creating it in.  The ListView continues to show data because nothing is telling it to change, but the ObservableCollection does not actually exist anymore.  You will want to create an observable collection that is global to the whole class, and populate it instead.

This is untested code, but should get you close... in code behind:

```
private ObservableCollection<Whatever> _myCollection;
public ObservableCollection<Whatever> MyCollection
{
    get
    {
        return _myCollection;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_myCollection != value) 
        {
            _myCollection = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("MyCollection");
        }
    }
}

private Whatever _selectedWhatever;
public Whatever SelectedWhatever
{
    get
    {
        return _selectedWhatever;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_selectedWhatever != value) 
        {
            _selectedWhatever = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedWhatever");
        }
    }
}

public ClientConfig()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    foreach (Whatever whatevs in Client.LocalDB.Values.ToObservableCollection()) 
    {
        MyCollection.Add(whatevs); // populate the collection this way and it will persist
    }
}
```

and in XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" Grid.RowSpan="7" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5,0" SelectionMode="Single" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ItemSource="{Binding MyCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedWhatever}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ClientIDandName}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Notice that you have now bound the collection to a persistent variable that can be changed, and you have bound the selected item to a specific instance of that collection.  Now you can bind your textboxes to the SelectedWhatever and changes made in one place should be reflected in the other place.

Comment: The ToObservableCollection I added when trying to find the problem. It wasn't working properly before that either. Also the Whatever Class you write in your answer is the Client class. the LocalDB is static and is global in my application. It just returns a Dictionary<string, Client>. So it is the same reference. If I close my window and reopen it the value are ok. I can also do a listView.Items.Refresh and the list View updates ok. I just can't select another item without reopening.  I am just thinking if the fact that I overloaded the equal method in Client that is creating the problem.

Comment: You say that you are implementing INotifyPropertyChanged, but I don't see where or how from your code sample.  If you are still having issues, you may want to be sure that when you change your selected item, it is actually raising a property changed notification.  Most of the "only works once" type problems that I have run into with WPF have to do with INotifyPropertyChanged not being implemented correctly - the design pattern I use isn't the only way to do it, but you need to make sure that the RaisePropertyChanged is being called every time you update a value.

Comment: The Client class inherits INotifyPropertyChanged. Not sure if it is properly implemented, probably not fully. But I found the issue, like I though it was the overload in the Client class that were the problem. I had overloaded the GetHashCode in client to return the HashCode of ClientName instead. So I removed it and had to change a couple of things, but my problem is fixed.